# Display cube and able to detect which side is touched

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es-2.0

I need to display cube in iphone which can be rotated and when touched on any side it should display which side has been touched

Comment: are You looking for the same in cocos2D or in UIKit?

Comment: anything is fine, UIKit, opengl, cocos3d or 2d

Comment: Have you coded something yet ? What are you asking exactly ? Do you need some advice on a particular technical point or do you want others to code it for you ?

Comment: did You refer this link It May Be help full to you   ?    :http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-programming-guide/#TouchEvents

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [**link**](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16182#post-91685) for the demo example for cocos3d 
 You Can Use  touches method instead of the accelerometer